# Python automatic versioning not happening with Github Actions

Tags: python, github-actions, pypi

I have an automated Github Actions workflow that is supposed to build and upload to pypi with the version of the release tag.

However, regardless of the tag, the action builds the packge with version 0.0.0
([see the run](https://github.com/RemDelaporteMathurin/pyEnergyDiagram/runs/6388717562?check_suite_focus=true#step:6:27))

Below are the build files:

GA workflow

```yaml
name: Upload Python Package

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  deploy:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: '3.x'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install build
    - name: Build package
      run: python -m build
    - name: Publish package
      uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@27b31702a0e7fc50959f5ad993c78deac1bdfc29
      with:
        user: __token__
        password: ${{ secrets.PYPI_API_TOKEN }}
```

setup.py

```py
import setuptools

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setuptools.setup()
```

setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = pyenergydiagram
author = Remi Delaporte-Mathurin
author_email = rdelaportemathurin@gmail.com
description = Plot potential energy diagram in python
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/RemDelaporteMathurin/pyEnergyDiagram
license = MIT
license_file = LICENSE
classifiers =
    Natural Language :: English
    Topic :: Scientific/Engineering
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9
    License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License
    Operating System :: OS Independent
project_urls =
    Source = https://github.com/RemDelaporteMathurin/pyEnergyDiagram
    Tracker = https://github.com/RemDelaporteMathurin/pyEnergyDiagram/issues

[options]
packages = find:
python_requires= >=3.6
install_requires =
    numpy >= 1.22
    matplotlib >= 3.5.1
    scipy >= 1.8

[options.extras_require]
tests = 
    pytest >= 5.4.3
```

project.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools >= 45",
    "wheel",
    "setuptools_scm[toml] >= 6.2",
    "setuptools_scm_git_archive",
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools_scm]
write_to = "pyenergydiagram/_version.py"
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file should be name "pyproject.toml" not "project.toml". Therefore it wasn't caught up by the actions.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to this, but based on this article:
https://medium.com/@VersuS_/automate-pypi-releases-with-github-actions-4c5a9cfe947d

Potentially changing your setup.py to include:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    setuptools.setup(version={{VERSION_PLACEHOLDER}})
```

and then editing your GA to include:

```
- name: Extract tag name
        id: tag
        run: echo ::set-output name=TAG_NAME::$(echo $GITHUB_REF | cut -d / -f 3)

- name: Update version in setup.py
        run: >-
          sed -i "s/{{VERSION_PLACEHOLDER}}/${{ steps.tag.outputs.TAG_NAME }}/g" setup.py
```

Hope that helps!